# How to filter by field values in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

Given the ElasticSearch document below:

```
{
    "_id": "3330481",
    "_type": "user",
    "_source": {
        "id": "3330481",
        "following": ["1", "2", "3", ... , "15000"]
    }
}
```

For a given user list ["50", "51", "52"] I want to check which ones are followed by the user with id 3330481. Since she is following 15000 users, I don't want to get the whole list and then check it locally.

Is there any way to retrieve only the relevant users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether you can fetch a sub-array from a doc.

However, one way of achieving this is by using nested fields. You can change the schema of  `following` field to be `nested` as below.

```
 {
        "id": "3330481",
        "following": [
              {"userId":"1"}, {"userId":"2"},{"userId": "3"}, ... ]
 }
```

Then you can use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) to retrieve your matching elements in the array as below.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "following",
            "query" : {
                "terms" : {"following.userId" : ["50","51","53"]}
            },
            "inner_hits" : {
                "size":0 // fetches all 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used inner_hits as suggested to solve my problem. However, I am not sure about 'size=0'. It didn't return any results unless I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to retrieve all user's flollowing with `["50", "51", "52"]` without affect score, you can use [minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) with bool query. Example:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "terms": {
              "following": ["50", "51", "52"],
              "minimum_should_match": 3
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in other users. I just want to check for the given user.